# Which language was first to introduce the "in" keyword first: SQL or Object Pascal?

Tags: sql, standards, delphi

(Or possibly another language?)

I know both SQL and Object Pascal first appeared in 1986, but I'm not sure which one had the `in` keyword first, so anyone who can point me to a definitive source will get my thanks and some reputation.

Yes I searched for the answer, but I think my Google-fu is weak. :(

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your motivation for asking this question?

Comment: @Greg, I suspect that (not being the OP, I can't be certain) the first three words of your comment answer your comment =)

Comment: @Rob you would be correct - it came up in random office chat and no-one knew the answer so I decided to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pascal itself had `in` much earlier than 1986 (Pascal was first published in 1970). It was used for set membership testing. My Pascal is rusty, but it went something like this:

```
type mysettype = set of 1..10;
var myset: mysettype;

if 5 in myset then begin
    writeln("found it!");
end;
```

Further information can be found on the [Wikipedia Pascal page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29#Set_types).

Also, here is a citation from Wirth's [PASCAL User Manual and Report](http://books.google.com/books?ei=zyusTMn9DI-esQOrj8G3Aw&ct=result&id=vy-zAAAAIAAJ&dq=pascal+wirth&q=in+operator#search_anchor) that mentions `in` as one of the relational operators.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle V2 was released in 1979 as a commercial relational database by Relational Software, Inc (using SQL before its standardisation by ANSI in 1986); followed by IBM's System R. The SQL-86 standard certainly included the IN operator, but can't confirm whether or not it appeared between 1979 and 1986.